# Does spark provide left shift or right shift operators?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I know it can be hacked by using UDF. But, does spark as in language provide functionality todo left and right shift operations. I have searched extensively on google and looked into the documentation but couldn't find it.

Comment: I hope you are looking for this - check bitwise operators- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#_3

Comment: @SomeshwarKale I have mentioned for left-shift and right-shift operator. Though they are the bitwise operators. But they are not mentioned in the document.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#shiftleft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use shiftleft and shiftright functions from spark- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#shiftleft
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#shiftright